# What is the chance...

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm not a mathematician just an ordinary person, I would like to know, what is the mathematical chance for this to happen:

A computer randomly chose 1 number out of 1024, how many times you need to try to find the number?

After each unsuccessful try the computer will randomly chose another number out of 1024 which you have to guess and so on until you find the right number.

Thanks

Comment: Mathematicians are ordinary people, too.

Comment: Thank you K.defaoite